# select the latest row with a specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table 1 of task progress like this
Table 1. Task

```
ID | TaskID | IsPlanned | MondayOfWeekDate| Progress | UserID | TaskCreationDate
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
18998 9917       1           2019-04-01    0           1150        2019-04-04 10:47:52.177
```

and I need to pick task progresses which has progress < 100 and TaskCreationDate is latest

I have tried using group by and max but i still get duplicated result

Here is my SQL so far

```
select TaskProgress.* 
from 
    (select 
         TaskID, Max(Progress) as Progress, Max(TaskCreationDate) as TaskCreationDate 
     from 
         TaskProgress
     group by 
         TaskID) as MaxValueTable 
join 
    TaskProgress on TaskProgress.TaskID = MaxValueTable.TaskID
                 and MaxValueTable.Progress = TaskProgress.Progress
                 and TaskProgress.Progress < 100
```

I expected to get task with latest date of creation and highest progress point

```
ID    | TaskID | IsPlanned | MondayOfWeekDate| Progress | UserID | TaskCreationDate 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
28885   19500       0           2019-03-25       90        1717   2019-03-25 07:57:36.560
```

But I still get this

```
ID    | TaskID | IsPlanned | MondayOfWeekDate| Progress | UserID | TaskCreationDate 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
28885   19500       0           2019-03-25       90        1717   2019-03-25 07:57:36.560
28696   19500       0           2019-03-11       90        1717   2019-03-16 20:57:57.373
28569   19500       0           2019-03-04       90        1717   2019-03-09 11:29:49.010
28485   19500       0           2019-02-25       90        1717   2019-03-02 18:12:25.587
28368   19500       0           2019-02-18       90        1717   2019-02-23 17:59:21.973
```

Please help me correct. Thank you in advance.

Comment: order by `TaskCreationDate` descending and use `limit 1`

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.)?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i am using SQL Server and I edited it

Comment: You say that you want the latest creation date _and_ highest progress point.  But what if two separate records have the highest values for each of these.  How do you handle this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I handle it by taskID

Answer (score 0):

You missed  the condition for  MaxValueTable.TaskCreationDate = TaskProgress.TaskCreationDate

```
select TaskProgress.* 
from  (
  select 
         TaskID
         , Max(Progress) as Progress
         , Max(TaskCreationDate) as TaskCreationDate 
  from TaskProgress
group by TaskID) as MaxValueTable 
join  TaskProgress on TaskProgress.TaskID = MaxValueTable.TaskID
                 and MaxValueTable.Progress = TaskProgress.Progress
                 and TaskProgress.Progress < 100
                 and  MaxValueTable.TaskCreationDate = TaskProgress.TaskCreationDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following test scenario:

```
create table TaskProgress
(
    TaskID int,
    Progress int,
    TaskCreationDate date
);
go

insert into TaskProgress values
    (1, 10, '2019-04-06'),
    (1, 20, '2019-04-07'),
    (1, 30, '2019-04-08'),
    (1, 60, '2019-04-09'),
    (1, 80, '2019-04-10'),
    (1, 90, '2019-04-11')
go
```

With this, your query seems to work correctly. As I expected. (Only remark is that you do NOT need the latest TaskCreationDate in your table expression, since you do not use or need it in your main query.)

**Are you really sure that you do not have duplicate combinations of TaskID and Progress in your TaskProgress table???**

Small update:

It seems that you say that you want the records that match the youngest TaskCreationDate. That's possible too, of course. You could change your query as follows:

```
select TaskProgress.* 
from 
    (select 
         TaskID, Max(Progress) as Progress, Max(TaskCreationDate) as TaskCreationDate 
     from 
         TaskProgress
     group by 
         TaskID) as MaxValueTable 
join 
    TaskProgress on TaskProgress.TaskID = MaxValueTable.TaskID
                 and MaxValueTable.TaskCreationDate = TaskProgress.TaskCreationDate
                 and TaskProgress.Progress < 100
```

In this case, you wouldn't need the highest progress in your table expression; it's not used.

Edit 2:

AAAAHHHHHH! I got it! I think...

You do need the highest progress value, since it should be less than 100. So you should probably check for the table expression's Progress value instead of the TaskProgress' Progress value.

Please try this:

```
select TaskProgress.* 
from 
    (select 
         TaskID, Max(Progress) as Progress, Max(TaskCreationDate) as TaskCreationDate 
     from 
         TaskProgress
     group by 
         TaskID) as MaxValueTable 
join 
    TaskProgress on TaskProgress.TaskID = MaxValueTable.TaskID
                 and MaxValueTable.TaskCreationDate = TaskProgress.TaskCreationDate
                 and MaxValueTable.Progress < 100
```

Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `TOP` and `ORDER BY`:

```
select top (1) tp.* 
from TaskProgress tp
where tp.Progress < 100
order by tp.Progress desc, TaskCreationDate desc;
```

If you want multiple rows in the case of ties, use `top (1) with ties`.